# Load image not as a rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to load image not as a rectangle?
I have some image of buildings looking like this and I want to make a hover effect only on the red area.
This will be another picture with `opacity: 0` and `opacity: 1` on hover.

[image]

EDIT:

For anyone looking for a solution to a similar problem all the answers got me into looking deeper. `clip-path` can do the job but has poor browser support. `<map>` is not very usefull if I want to change the background color etc. of selected area. What worked for me best is using `SVG` with `polygons`. SVG area is the same size as my background image and polygons match areas I want.
Scaling is also done right away and `CSS` can be used.

Comment: Is "another picture" only for that red area? Or it is another picture the same size but with a different look in the red area?

Comment: The `<map>` [element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You can clip the image to a path - works like a mask in photoshop for example. So you would draw a path around the area and clip the image to this path.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip-path/

```css
img {
  clip-path: polygon(5% 5%, 100% 0%, 100% 75%, 75% 75%, 75% 100%, 50% 75%, 0% 75%);
}
```

Note that browser support is not that good, so you might be better off using a transparent .png file though.
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use a html `map` with an [area](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp) on it to get a hover effect just like that:

```html
<!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fhAK.jpg" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="" alt="My hover element" title="My hover element" href="" coords="764,748,621,494,620,409,1040,317,1108,365,755,453,872,619,888,716" shape="poly">
</map>
```

I used the tool https://www.image-map.net/ to generate it.